# How to pull the ROM image from a MMC?

Tags: image, dump, burn, rom

I have bought a device with a pre-burned image on it. Can I pull (or dump) the image from it so I will be able to burn it to a similar device?

I know I can backup a device with TWRP. But that does not give me the complete ROM.

Can I use dd to extract the whole MMC to a SD card?